# Removing punctuation on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, web

I have code set up that loops through check-boxes and creates a list of the results on the top of an accordion menu. When you click the X next to each term they delete themselves and uncheck the box associated with it. However the separating commas and the colon at the start of the list remain when the tags are removed. I have a heavy handed way of dealing with this, but I feel like it could be much cleaner and faster but the solution I came up with keeps giving me syntax errors.

```
var divBlock = $(this).closest("h3 + div"); //finds parent h3 + div
aObject = divBlock.prev().find("a:first"); //gets the a link in the h3
originaltitle = aObject.html();

var liItems = divBlock.find("li");
for (var i = 0; i < liItems.length; i++) {
    if (liItems[i].childNodes[0].checked) {
        var searchterm = liItems[i].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
        categoryString += "<div class='choice'>" + searchterm + "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"delete_search_term\" id=\"close_" + searchterm.replace(/\s/g, "-") + "\">(x)</a>,</div> ";
    }
}

if (originaltitle.indexOf(": ") > 0) {
    originaltitle = originaltitle.substring(0, originaltitle.indexOf(":"));
}

if (categoryString.length > 0) {
    categoryString = categoryString.substring(0, categoryString.lastIndexOf(",")) + "</div>";
    aObject.html(originaltitle + ": " + categoryString);
} else {
    aObject.html(originaltitle.replace(":", "").trim());
}
```

That code handles the creation of the strings and placement of the punctuation to format the list. The following code is kind of my do everything mish-mash that throws errors unless I comment out my subsub code.

```
$("a.delete_search_term").click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    var itemName = this.id.replace("close_", "").toLowerCase();
    var liItems = $(this).closest("h3").next().find("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < liItems.length; i++) {
        if (liItems[i].childNodes[0].id == itemName) {
            liItems[i].childNodes[0].checked = false;
        }
    }
    if (categoryString.length > 0) {
        categoryString = categoryString.substring(categoryString.lastIndexOf(","));
        subsub = categoryString.substring(0, 1);
        $(subsub).remove();
    }
    $(this).parent().remove(); //Removes parent of selected object only
    return false;
});
```

Created a JSFiddle by request:  http://jsfiddle.net/w4AxR/1/

Comment: When I remove one item all of the items go away in you jsfiddle.

Comment: Yea sorry about that Ill put it back, I had the code commented out for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked your fiddle and modified the code.  The process could be simplified quite a bit by just using classes on the inputs that the user has chosen.

Instead of trying to manipulate the list in the H3 on changes, I made the code simply manage the classes on the inputs and rebuild the list on every change.

The code becomes much more simple:

```
var updateChoices = function () {
    var container = $(".acat1");

    container.text('Food Categories: ');
    $('li.selected input').each(function () {
        var searchterm = $(this).next().text();
        var element = $('<div />').addClass('choice').text(searchterm).append(
            $('<a />').addClass('delete-search-term').attr('id', 'remove_' + this.id ).text('(x),')
        );
        container.append(element);
    });
    var lastChoice = container.find('.choice:last');
    lastChoice.html(lastChoice.html().replace(",", ""));
}

$('.check').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    else $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');

    updateChoices();
});

$("a.delete-search-term").live('click', function () {
    $('#' + this.id.replace('remove_', '') )
        .attr('checked', false)
        .parent().removeClass('selected');

    updateChoices();

    return false;
});
```

Full Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FQcG/3/)

Currently, the jsfiddle you provided was only using jquery 1.6.4, not sure if that was intentional.  If so, might want to look into upgrading for `.on()` support for event binds.  I used a `.live()` since on was not yet supported.

**edit:** Changed it so adding a filter and removing a filter reuse the same functionality to populate the list.

Comment: Thank you very much for shrinking and simplifying the code that is beautiful. However it still suffers from the same defects my code does. If you delete items from right to left it leaves the trailing comma and that is what has been plaguing me.

Comment: funny, changed it right before I answered cause I forgot why I had made a separate function.  editing the answer.

Comment: Close enough that I can finish up from here. Thank you so very much good sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
subsub = categoryString.substring(0,1);
$(subsub).remove();
```

substring returns a string, `$(X).remove()` needs an selector......if subsub contains an id do

```
$('#'+subsub).remove();
```

or an class string

```
$('.'+subsub).remove();
```

[EDIT] actually....substring(0,1) returns a single char....is it meant like that?

Comment: Yes it is supposed only return the "," for removal. Trying your string, it deletes all the terms at once, though to be fair the commas went with them.